# Duplicate Rows -- Join Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find our top selling product, and then use that information to find other things. However, we recently moved information to a new table in our database. The new table has new item numbers but only some of the old originals. When I join the old table to get all, they double up a lot because the new table has more data than the old.

I'm really wordy and confusing so here's an example:

```
ItemName    ItemNo    ItemNo2   Size    Age     Type          Count  Sales      YearNew
Item1       AA123     AA123     ST      NULL    Accessories   1234   12334.56   2008
Item2       BB123     BB123     ST      Adult   Accessories   5643   98765.43   2006
Item3       CC123     CC123     ST      NULL    Accessories   1111   11111.11   2007
Item3b      CC123     CC123     ST      Adult   Accessories   1111   11111.11   2007
Item4       DD123     DD123     L       Kids    Costumes      333    7891.12    2011
Item4       DD123     DD123     L       Teen    Costumes      333    7891.12    2011
```

(these numbers are made up, obviously)

Note that for Item3 and Item3b the only difference is the ItemName and the Age. Everything else is the same. But because that's different and I'm grouping by every field, it's splitting them into 2 mostly duplicate lines.

Is there a way I can join the ItemNo and ItemNo2 columns? Or another method of solving this?

But also note that I have situations where every single column is the same, except for the type or the age. DD123 in this example is the same in every area except for Age, which causes it to split to two lines as well.

Other times, it's all identical except for the ItemName. It varies all over.

It was suggested to me that I ask programming to simply add the old item numbers they left out back into the new table. Would that be the best method or is there something I can do on my end?

I have **read-only access** to the database so I can't make any changes myself.

For fun, here's the query I'm using at the moment:

```
select PM.ProductMasterName as ItemName,PM.ItemNumber as ItemNo,
    op.ItemNumber_obsolete as ItemNo2,
    OP.Size_obsolete as Size,Age.AgeSegment as Age,
    PT.ProductTypeDescription as Type,PM.Price,
    COUNT(PM.ItemNumber) as 'Count',
    (PM.Price*COUNT(PM.ItemNumber)) as Sales,
    YEAR(PS.DateCreated) as YearNew
from dbo.tblOrder O with (nolock)
    left outer join dbo.tblOrderProduct OP with (nolock)
        on O.OrderID=op.OrderID
    left outer join dbo.tblProductSize PS
        on OP.ItemNumber_obsolete=PS.ItemNumber_obsolete
            and OP.Size_obsolete=PS.Size_obsolete
    left outer join Product.ProductMaster PM with (nolock)
        on PM.ItemNumber=OP.ItemNumber_obsolete
            and PM.Price=OP.Price
    left outer join Product.ProductType PT
        on PM.ProductTypeID=PT.ProductTypeID
    left outer join Product.AgeSegmentToProductMaster ASPM
        on PM.ProductMasterID=ASPM.ProductMasterID
    left outer join Product.AgeSegment Age
        on ASPM.AgeSegmentID=Age.AgeSegmentID
where O.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
    and O.OrderDate < '2013-01-01'
group by PM.ProductMasterName,PM.ItemNumber,op.ItemNumber_obsolete,
    OP.Size_obsolete,PM.Price,Age.AgeSegment,
    PT.ProductTypeDescription,YEAR(PS.DateCreated)
order by Sales desc
```

Comment: I want you to understand that if one piece of data is differnt it should be a separate row in teh result set, that is how SQL works by design. You do not have like records.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to select only one row for a given "itemNo" for the new table.  You can do this by using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemNo order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from newt t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This chooses an arbitrary row.  If you have a way of distinguishing between the two tables (so you get the "new" version in this case, for instance), then you can use that.

Also, I'm not sure if you want `ItemNo` or `ItemNo, ItemNo2` for the partition.

Another approach you can take, to eliminate the NULL values, is to aggregate by `itemNo`:

```
select ItemNo, max(ItemName) as ItemName, max(size) as size, max(age) as age, . . .
from newT
group by ItemNo;
```

This will eliminate the `NULL` values (based on the data in the example).

Comment: Nice solution, forgot about this technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Creating temp repository to hold test data.
CREATE TABLE #T ( Id int IDENTITY(1,1), ItemName VARCHAR(20), ItemNo VARCHAR(20), ItemNo2 VARCHAR(20), Size VARCHAR(20), Age VARCHAR(20), [Type] VARCHAR(20), [Count] VARCHAR(20), Sales VARCHAR(20), YearNew VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO #T ( ItemName, ItemNo, ItemNo2, Size, Age, [Type], [Count], Sales, YearNew  )
SELECT 'Item1','AA123','AA123','ST','NULL','Accessories','1234','12334.56','2008' UNION
SELECT 'Item2','BB123','BB123','ST','Adult','Accessories','5643','98765.43','2006' UNION
SELECT 'Item3','CC123','CC123','ST','NULL','Accessories','1111','11111.11','2007' UNION
SELECT 'Item3b','CC123','CC123','ST','Adult','Accessories','1111','11111.11','2007' UNION
SELECT 'Item4','DD123','DD123','L','Kids','Costumes','333','7891.12','2011' UNION
SELECT 'Item4','DD123','DD123','L','Teen','Costumes','333','7891.12','2011' 

-- Use last records data when there are dupliate ItemNo values
SELECT T.*
FROM #T T
JOIN 
(
    SELECT ItemNo, Id = MAX(Id)
    FROM #T
    GROUP BY ItemNo
) X ON X.Id = T.Id
```